# C++11: Variadic Template Function Parameter Pack Expansion Execution Order

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, variadic-functions

Consider the following code:

```
template<class T>
size_t f(T t, size_t& x) { return x++; }

template<class... Args>
void g(Args... args)
{
    size_t x = 0;
    size_t y[] = { f(args, x)... };

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(args); i++)
        assert(y[i] == i);
}
```

Is the assert guaranteed by the C++11 standard not to fire?  Why or why not?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes it's guaranteed not to fire. See the following quotes:

§14.5.3 Variadic templates:

> Pack expansions can occur in [...] an initializer-list; the pattern is
>   an initializer-clause.

§8.5.1 Aggregates:

> The full-expressions in an initializer-clause are evaluated in the
>   order in which they appear.

Comment: Does this mean if I had of written `size_t y[] = { f(args, x++)... };`, it would of also worked?

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling ...and `f` just `return x;`? Yes. It means that.

Comment: I remember something about parameter packs not being evaluated in order in some circumstance.  (Perhaps as the parameters to a function call.)

Comment: @AndrewTomazos-Fathomling parameter packs don't do anything special. No function arguments (parameter packs or not) are guaranteed to be evaluated in a particular order.

Comment: In particular this means that in the case of a constructor call, e.g. `T t( pattern(args)...);`, the order of evaluation is unspecified whereas when using a brace initializer, e.g. `T t { pattern(args)... };` the order is well-defined even though the latter might end up making a call to the same constructor as in the former.

Comment: @Luc in fact I rcommend using the `T{pattern(args)...}` approach over the array approach like `int dummy[]={pattern(args)...}` approach, because the latter is ill-formed when `args` is empty.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Ummm, it seems to work ok. See here: http://ideone.com/7RvBX - is this nonstandard behaviour?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: `s/bug/feature/`

Comment: ideone.com doesn't show warnings, but with clang I get `warning: zero size arrays are an extension [-Wpedantic]`. So it's not an accident that it's accepted, but if you want to write portable code such extensions should be avoided.